# Check if we can form a word across words in a sentence

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, strings

I've come across a simple challenge: given a phrase, check if we can form the given word vertically by stacking words in rows. For example, we can form the word `"boom"` from this phrase:

every **b**reath
            y**o**u take
every m**o**ve
      you **m**ake

My Python code:

```
def can_spell(s, w):
    words = s.split()
    words_iter = iter(words)

    for char in w:
        try:
            next_word = next(words_iter)
            while char not in next_word:
                next_word = next(words_iter)
        except StopIteration:
            return False
    return True


print(can_spell('every breath you take every move you make', 'boom'))  # True
```

Is this the most efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Staying close to your original appraoch, you could use another `for` loop with an `else` instead of `try/except` and `while`. The `else` is triggered when the inner loop has ended normally, without the `break`, i.e. when there are no more parts left in the sentence.

```
def can_spell(sentence, word):
    words_iter = iter(sentence.split())
    for char in word:
        for part in words_iter:
            if char in part:
                break
        else:
            return False
    return True
```

Or, you could use a nested generator expression checking that `all` characters in the word are in `any` of the remaining parts of the sentence-iterator. This works since `any` will only consume as many items from the iterator as necessary until it finds a match.

```
def can_spell(sentence, word):
    words_iter = iter(sentence.split())
    return all(any(char in part for part in words_iter) for char in word)
```

---

Following an entirely different route, you could use a regular expression, joining the characters of the word such that between each character there has to be at least one space (and, optionally, any other characters), e.g. `b.* .*o.* .*o.* .*m` for `boom`, and check if that regular expression can be found in the sentence:

```
import re
def can_spell(sentence, word):
    return re.search('.* .*'.join(word), sentence) is not None
```

Comment: For each appraoch, performance should be O(n) with n being the number of characters in the sentence. `timeit` was inconclusive due to caching.

Comment: Nice regex approach.  I would use `.*\s+.*` (properly escaped of course) to catch tabs or newlines between words.  I’d be tempted to explore `.*\b.*` too; depends on how you define a word.

Comment: @AJNeufeld Agreed, but from the question I'd guess that the "sentence" will always be just a space-separated list of lower-case words, not line breaks, tabs or punctuation.